# Time Proportional control

Tags: thermocouple

I am developing application for Time Proportional Control of thermostat. I know that the output for heater is proportional to an error. For example, if SetPoint is 20 and proportional band is 2, in case if actual temperature (AT) is 19, then Output would be 50%. However, I can not figure out what happens if AT is higher than 20? For example if AT is 21, then output would be again 50%, that does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking at the absolute value of the error; instead, you should calculate the error as a positive or negative value.  If you only have one-directional control (e.g., no active cooling), you should just do nothing when the actual temperature is above the set point.

Specifically for your two examples:

- When AT=19, error = +1, output = heater on 50%
- When AT=21, error = -1, output = heater off

Edit:

- When AT=20, error = 0, output = heater off

Pseudo-code is something like:

```
const Kp = 1/2.
error = SP - AT
control_output = Kp * error 
set_heater_power(clip(control_output, 0.0, 1.0))
```

Comment: I wish I had higher reputation to rise your answer

Comment: Then what happens if AT = 20?

Comment: @AidosAskhatuly - see edit for more detail